# NPE when instantiating a convertView

Tags: android

Here is my code to create a custom view for a `ListView`. It uses a custom view named `SquareProgressBar`:

```
package com.example.simpledownloader.adapter;

import net.yscs.android.square_progressbar.SquareProgressBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.simpledownloader.R;
import com.example.simpledownloader.sharable.Sharable;

public class TaskAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx = null;


    public TaskAdapter(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Sharable.downloads.size();
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return Sharable.downloads.get(index);
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task, parent, false);
        }
        SquareProgressBar taskProgressBar = (SquareProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskProgressBar);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusMsg);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskName);

        taskProgressBar.setProgress((int)Sharable.downloads.get(index).getProgress());
        taskProgressBar.setImage(R.drawable.task_image);
        taskProgressBar.setColor("#C9C9C9");
        taskProgressBar.setWidth(8);
        name.setText(Sharable.downloads.get(index).toString());
        statusMsg.setText(Sharable.downloads.get(index).getStatus());

        return convertView;
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

However, I get a NPE:

```
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at net.yscs.android.square_progressbar.SquareProgressBar.setOpacity(SquareProgressBar.java:184)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at net.yscs.android.square_progressbar.SquareProgressBar.setProgress(SquareProgressBar.java:105)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at com.example.simpledownloader.adapter.TaskAdapter.getView(TaskAdapter.java:47)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-18 15:10:56.184: E/AndroidRuntime(5639):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Why is that?**
*I guess it is that the square progress bar is not found.*
*CTX is application context that is passed to this class*
*Sharable is a custom class which contains all singleton objects that are shared across activities*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
taskProgressBar.setProgress((int)Sharable.downloads.get(index).getProgress());
taskProgressBar.setImage(R.drawable.task_image);
```

use:

```
taskProgressBar.setImage(R.drawable.task_image);
taskProgressBar.setProgress((int)Sharable.downloads.get(index).getProgress());
```

Comment: Oh so the image inside was null .. damn !! :D

Comment: @LittleChild You didn't looked at the source code for the library:)

Comment: Seems quite logic even without having a look at the source code, no ?

Comment: Ok, although I dont get an NPE anymore, I am unable to get it to work. I tried setting `setProgress(50)` in the `getView()` but it didnt help.

Comment: @LittleChild And what exactly happens? You don't see any progress, the progress doesn't changes?

Comment: @Luksprog Sorry for the late reply. Yes, it does not change. And shows only 50% when a file has completed downloading

Comment: @LittleChild First make sure that you register correctly the progress in that `Sharable` class from which the progress its retrieved. I'm going to look through the library and make some commits this weekend.

Comment: @Luksprog See the answer by `yansigner`. He is the one who made that widget

Comment: @LittleChild I know he's the one that made the library, I've sent him a message about this question a couple of days before.

Comment: @Luksprog I could not find his email anywhere.. how did u mesage him ?

Comment: @LittleChild On his github user page https://github.com/mrwonderman you have his site and from there a link to his google plus profile.

Answer (score 1):

@LittleChild Please try the following code to solve your problem. After you set the progress and everything, set the opacity to false.

```
taskProgressBar.setOpacity(false);
```

Otherwise please create a new issue here (https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar/issues) with your code, so I can fix it as soon as possible.

**Update:** I tried it myself now and the opacity was the problem. I fixed this in the 1.3.0 branch now , which will roll out soon.

Comment: I have another issue where the progress bar does not update even after `setOpacity(false)`. I display how much of a file has been downloaded in `getView()` of my custom adapter but `SquareProgressBar` does not update even after `notifyDataSetChanged()` to the adapter. Works good in normal `ProgressBar` though. See: http://imgur.com/q0KzPPv

Comment: The logcat shows how many bytes of a file have been downloaded. :)